# How to have columns in table that don't have to be specified in post request

Tags: vapor

I have a Vapor app where I want some values to be specified by the user in a POST request, and other values to be computed based on the user-specified values.

For example, suppose the user patches in some new values, and each time that happens the table should automatically update a column with the current time.

I was looking at trying to store the computed properties in the database, but when I modified the model to know about the computed properties, all my POST requests began expecting those to be specified.

What's the most idiomatic way to have columns in a table that don't have to be specified by the post requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only looking to update a modified or created timestamp then there are two other ways. In your model, put:

```
static let createdAtKey: TimestampKey? = \.createdAt
static let updatedAtKey: TimestampKey? = \.updatedAt
var createdAt:Date?
var updatedAt:Date?
```

And let vapor do it for you, see [here](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/fluent/models/#creation-and-last-update-timestamps). Alternatively, you can make use of the methods `willCreate`, `willUpdate`, etc. as described in the docs [here](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/fluent/models/#lifecycle) if you are updating fields that do not need the user's input.

```
extension User
{
    func willUpdate(on connection: Database.Connection) throws -> Future<User>
    {
        modifiedCount += 1
        return Future.map(on: connection) { self }
    }
}
```

Finally, if you need a bit more flexibility than your own solution, consider using this in your controller:

```
struct EditUserForm:Content
{
    let id:Int
    let surname:String
    let initials:String
}

func save(_ request:Request) throws -> Future<View>
{
    return try request.content.decode(EditUserForm.self).flatMap
    {
        newUserData in
        return try request.parameters.next(User.self).flatMap
        {
            originalUser in
            // update fields as required, EditUserForm only has a subset
            return originalUser.save(on:request).transform(to:try self.index(request))
        }
    }
}
```

You will need the usual route:

```
router.post(User.parameter, "save", use:userController.save)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that I need to make the computed fields be optional in the model, and then compute them in the route function before saving.

#### For example:

Making `modified_date` be optional in the model:

```swift
final class MyContentType: PostgreSQLModel {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String
    var modified_date: Date?
}
```

Setting `modified_date` to the computed value:

```swift
    func create(_ request: Request, content: MyContentType) throws -> Future< MyContentType > {
        content.modified_date = Date()
        return content.save(on: request)
    }
```